# Show/hide Item meta data based on order status in WooCommerce "My account" view order pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I need to hide the wc item meta of a product in My Accounts > View order while the order status is pending.

I still want the wc item meta to appear once the order is complete in My Accounts > View order and also the checkout confirmation and email. Just hide it while it's pending as we have a reason for it to be hidden.

See attachments for clarity:

[image: Order status]

---

I am currently using some CSS

```css
.wc-item-meta {
    display: none;
}
```

But this blocks it out completely from My Accounts > View order. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't prefer to hide things via CSS, is it the easiest solution for your question. First of all we are going to add an extra CSS class that contains the status of the current order

```php
function action_woocommerce_order_details_before_order_table( $order ) {
    echo '<div class="' . $order->get_status() . '"></div>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_before_order_table', 'action_woocommerce_order_details_before_order_table', 10, 1 );
```

After the above has been done you can apply the following CSS, based on the pending order status

```css
.woocommerce-order-details .pending ~ .order_details .wc-item-meta {
    display: none;
}
```

---

Related: [Hide item meta data in certain WooCommerce email notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72256607/11987538)